# Monotouch / iPhone 5 and developing

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios6, iphone-5

I am trying to write an app that I want to be compatible with the iPhone 5 and 4.  I have read the excellent article [Get your MonoTouch apps ready for iPhone 5 / iOS 6 today!](http://redth.info/get-your-monotouch-apps-ready-for-iphone-5-ios-6-today/) but this implies you have to add a UIImage to each UIViewController to force it into displaying at the new resolution.  It also implies I then have to do this for every UIViewController I add.

My obvious question is what happens if I don't want a background image?  What if I want just a standard UITableVIew that uses the whole screen?  What would happen if I want to support both resolutions I can't just put an image into the directory. How do you handle that?  Is this really how Apple have designed it - you need to load a blank image?

Have I missed something really obvious?  Hope so.

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the *tall* screen working on your application (for the iPhone 5 or in the iOS6 simulator) you **only** need to have a *single* `Default-568h@2x.png` file, of the right size, in your application.

The article you link to talks in more details about how to deal with backgrounds - but that's **optional**, i.e. you only need this if you have (or want) a background for your views.